# spring roo(gvnix) not working in ie

Tags: spring-roo, gvnix

I created one simple project(creating users) using spring roo( gvnix) and deployed in tomcat7 and while browsing in chrome and microsoft edge it is working fine but while browsing in IE(11). The top fixed menu is not displaying. Below is my index.jspx code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/jquery/util" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <spring:message code="application_name" htmlEscape="false" var="app_name"/>
    <spring:message arguments="${app_name}" code="welcome_titlepane" htmlEscape="false" var="title"/>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1><spring:message arguments="${app_name}" code="welcome_h3"/></h1>
            <p><spring:message code="welcome_text"/></p>
        </div>

</div>
```

Could you please let me know where I am wrong?

using microsoft edge

[image: using microsoft edge]

using ie(11)

[image: using ie(11)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem and solved it.

Go to `WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx`

Set `<jsp:output doctype-root-element="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>`

instead of

```
<jsp:output doctype-root-element="HTML" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
```

and comment:

```
<!-- <meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>  -->
```

Let me know if this fix the problem